# Fluid simulation on GPU, get data to client

Tags: opengl, gpu, physics

I would like to build a program that lets the user draw a wing profile, and then do a real time simulation of the air flowing around this profile. The calculations are to be done on the GPU.

I made a design for the program that you can see in this oh so ugly MS Paint drawing:

[image: Computation Flowchart]
Shader Program 2 uses Texture 1, which is a grid of particles, does collision detection, and renders it to Texture 2. Then Program 1 uses the updated grid, calculates a time step, and renders this to Texture 1 in Framebuffer Object 1. Every now and then Program 3 renders this texture to the screen.

I am lost at the step of getting information back to the client side in a way that doesn't completely stall the gpu. The only thing I want to get back is the lift generated on the wing. Every time a particle collides with the wing, it transfers momentum to the wing. I need a way of adding all those tiny bits of momentum, and calculate the average force on the wing over multiple frames.

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe this question is a super good fit for the site because it's very localized while still being too open ended but let me take a pass at it anyways since GPU accelerated fluid simulation was my senior project and, let's face it, it's really fun.

First of all, I would recommend against doing all of this in OpenGL and instead opt for [OpenCL](https://www.khronos.org/opencl/). It's made for general computation so you'll have a much easier time getting data back and forth in a sensible, domain-specific way (for example, you don't have to think in terms of textures and all that graphics-specific jazz).

If you're rendering with OpenGL and computing with OpenCL, you can [share some of your buffers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/OpenCL_MacProgGuide/shareGroups/shareGroups.html) to avoid unnecessary copies from a context to the other. I would compute all the particle positions in an OpenCL buffer, share that buffer with OpenGL and use a [geometry shader](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Geometry_Shader) to emit the graphics primitives that make up the fluid's rendering.

Second, you'll have to accept that getting data back from the GPU is always going to be expensive. If you can avoid needing it on the host, do that. Otherwise, you pretty much have 2 options:

1. Write every particle's transferred momentum to the wing in an OpenCL buffer of length `particle_count`, read it into host memory, then sum those on the CPU.
2. Sum the force on the wing on the GPU in a `sizeof(force_type)` sized buffer using [`atomic_add`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/atomic_add.html) and only read that into host memory.

Option 2 might be faster than option 1 or it might be slower  depending on a huge number of factors ranging from the amount of particles you have to your graphics driver so you'll need to experiment and benchmark (which is generally a thing you want to be doing all the time when doing GPGPU like this).

Your idea of alternating between 2 textures is a really good insight by the way. It'll allow you to avoid the issues related to "sheared" data (some particles are updated but some aren't). You should always read from a single buffer and write to a different one. Of course, that has a cost in the amount of VRAM you'll be using.

Finally, if you want to look at how we personally did it in OpenCL, take a look at [`libclsph`](https://github.com/libclsph/libclsph). Keep in mind it's not production ready at all, the collision system is a terrible approximation (at best) and it shows that it was a student project. It's also geared towards graphics and an external renderer so we write the particles to a file and we don't compute forces on the environment. Nevertheless, it's a good starting example of how one could approach fluid simulation in OpenCL.

Let me know if you need more info and good luck. There's lots of things to think about but it's a cool project!